# If the equation is exact, solve: $(2x-1)dx + (3y+7)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand the concept of determining if a differential equation is exact. My professor told me that the general strategy is as follows:

The term in front of $dx = M$
The term in front of $dy = N$

Check if $Mx = Ny$. If so, the DE is exact. If not, you cannot go any further.

In the equation in the title of this question I found that $My = 2$ while $Ny = 3$. However, the back of the book tells me that there is a solution. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Where you have $Mx$, it should really be $$M_x=\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$$. Ditto $Ny$ should be $$N_y=\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}$$. Those are also backwards. You check $M_y ?= N_x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2x-1)dx + (3y+7)dy = 0 = F_x\, dx+F_y\, dy$$  where $$F_x = 2x-1, \quad F_y = 3y+7, F_{xy} = F_{yx} = 0 $$  we can integrate $F_x = 2x-1$ with respect to $x$ and get $$F = x^2 - x + c(y) \to F_y = c'(y) = 3y + 7\to c = \frac32 y^2+7y $$  therefore $$x^2 - x + \frac32 y^2+7y = constant $$ is a solution.

Comment: Wait why doesn't your answer involve some sort of "test" to see if the equation is exact or not? That seems to be the first part of the strategy taught to us in class. Is this actually not needed?

Comment: the test is  done in the  second line where i verified that $F_{xy} = F_{yx}.$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is one in which the terms involving $x$ and the terms involving $y$ can be separated. In other words we have $(2x-1)dx=-(3y+7)dy$ which can be integrated on both sides. Such an equation is also called variable separable.

Every variable separable equation is exact as can be verified by the test $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ where $M$ is the coefficient of $dx$ and $N$ the coefficient of $dy$ in $Mdx+Ndy=0$. Here $M$ is a function of $x$ and $N$ is a function of $y$ and so the test reduces to both $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ being $0$.

Comment: Am i understanding variable separable correctly - does it simply mean that you can isolate all the $x's$ and all the $y's$ to opposite sides?

Comment: @DarthVoid: Yes, thats what it means.